Disable suggestions everywhere except on the current line
I am using LazyVim, I love the snippet/keyword/text suggestions it is giving me (like completing i32 in the screenshot below). I have begun to notice that it also adds grey text in variables where type is not specified in Rust and other minor suggestions in places here and there where I am not writing code.
I want to disable this as it creates unnecessary distraction while writing code, I will fix them if needed by myself later.

For example, here in the 4th line from the top it suggests : char in grey color, which is not actually present and is a suggestion, this creates the illusion that the datatype is specified if seen in a hurry.
Also, I am aware that I would have to tweak nvim-cmp and maybe the rust-analyzer, too, but I am unable to implement it just by reading the docs.
How to disable all suggestions in a buffer other than the line in which I am writing?

These are inlay hints.
You can disable inlay hints with the following command:
vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(false)

Of in Vimscript:
lua vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(false)

If you want to disable it from the start you could have a nvim/lua/plugins/lazyvim.lua file with the following content:
return {
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    opts = {
      -- autoformat = false,
      inlay_hints = {enabled = false},
    },
  },
}


This doesn't stop the suggestion from showing.

Thanks for the feedback! When you have the suggestion and ran the command, do you still have them?

Ok, I checked it again, On adding the line to options.lua (standard file for LazyVim for storing options) the suggestions are still showing up, but running it with :lua vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(false) in the buffer closes the suggestions, now I think I would have to look up why it is not working in options.lua, Still thanks for the answer!!

Thanks for your feedback! I have updated the solution with the instruction to adapt the LazyVim configuration accordingly :-)

Thanks for your time and great answer, it de cluttered my code, it somehow completely slipped my mind that the changes would have to be made in some plugin related to LSP, I could have saved some time of yours, still thanks again.

I'm happy to help you! I'm sure your are not alone. The answer will also help others :-)
